# Using For-Variables for Django Model column

Tags: python, django, django-models

I don't know if it's possible. Hopefully you guys knows what I try to do. I want to do the model changes in a FOR loop cause the keys of the values have always the same name as the model columns.

My current code:

```
sites = DataModel.objects.all()
for site in sites:
    d = self.getDataBySoup(soup)
    site.title = d['title']
    site.text = d['text']
    site.facebook = d['facebook']
    site.twitter = d['twitter']
    site.save()
```

As you can see, the keys are always the same as the django columns. So I thought its maybe possible to do it with less code.

What I tried (but it's not working):

```
sites = DataModel.objects.all()
for site in sites:
    d = self.getDataBySoup(soup)
    for key, value in d.items():
        site.key = value
    site.save()
```

I use Python 3.6

getDataBySoup Method is just returning a dict/array:

```
def getContentDataBySoup(self, soup):
    data = {}
    data['title'] = 'some text'
    # etc
    return data
```

etc.

Comment: Have you tried: `DataModel(**d)` ?

Comment: Do you really want to update all existing sites with the same `d`? Almost looks like `d` should return something that indicates a specific site and you should be updating that...

Comment: I didnt try it. And yes, site coloum name is always same with d key

Comment: Might want to show your `getDataBySoup` method and explain what you're trying to do... If `d` is a `dict` with `title`,`text`,`facebook` and `twitter`, then `DataModel(**d)` is the same as `DataModel(title=d['title'], text=d['text'],...)`

Comment: I just give d a dict/array.
Like d = {}
d['title'] = 'some text'

Comment: Okay... but are you deliberately wanting to loop over all existing objects and set everyone of them to those values?

Comment: Yes Jon, exactly.

Comment: I've already explained what the `**` is equivalent to... So if that's really what you want, your exact equivalent of the code would be `DataModel.objects.update(**d)`...

Answer (score 0):

```
sites = DataModel.objects.all()
for site in sites:
    d = self.getDataBySoup(soup)
    DataModel.objects.filter(id=site.pk).update(**d)
```

The code above would update each site entry with the data in the dictionary d. If you're using the update method it's important that you also specify the id, otherwise it won't know what entry to update.

Comment: django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: app_data.id
Thats the error I get then. I also tried with a new dict, with just the title. But doesnt help.

Comment: @bonblow My bad, you'd have to filter on the id first if you want to update that specific object. I've updated my answer to reflect that.